# Filter returns questions which do not match any of the wildcard expressions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-synonyms

[This tag filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/30258/rfc) selects questions which match the following wildcard tag pattern:

```
*mail* OR rfc* OR *smtp*
```

The filter is returning questions tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php), which does not match any of the wildcard expressions.

Perhaps it is an unintended side effect of tag synonyms interacting with the filter algorithm. In this case someone has created [a tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/synonyms) of [php](/questions/tagged/php) named [php-mail](/questions/tagged/php-mail). It is correct for the expansion of the tag pattern to include [php-mail](/questions/tagged/php-mail). But it is wrong for the filter algorithm to return questions that are tagged with [php](/questions/tagged/php), which does not match the wildcard expressions in the pattern.

Comment: To be honest, that seems like a good candidate for purging the weird synonym. Normally synonyms *should* interact with tag filters this way.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Is it weird? I think there are a lot of related tags tied together as "synonyms" when they are not synonymous. I figured that was accepted practice.

Comment: It's pretty sketchy to synonymize some random bit of PHP with PHP itself; the only reason for that is the fecklessness of askers who think it's relevant to tag some random bit of PHP. So it's basically just tag filters interacting with a hack to remove a bad tag.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've considered it, and I am still convinced that a wildcard search should not return results that aren't expansions of the wildcard. The filter algorithm absolutely should not match `*mail*` to [tag:php]. The very fact that the search results can be completely bollocksed by some site's bad tag synonym shows how wrong this approach is.

Comment: Well, there's certainly something deeply wrong, but I'd argue that it's at least as much a result of the inferior tag moderation tools available. Tags are third-class citizens, and boy does it show.

Answer (score 2):

> Filter returns questions which do not match any of the wildcard expressions

This is by-design: When filtering by tags, synonyms are taken into account. If [electronic-mail](/questions/tagged/electronic-mail) is a synonym of [email](/questions/tagged/email) you certainly want to get [email](/questions/tagged/email) questions when asking for [electronic-mail](/questions/tagged/electronic-mail): they will all be retagged [email](/questions/tagged/email).

> In this case someone has created a tag synonym of php named php-mail.

[php-mail](/questions/tagged/php-mail) should not a synonym of [php](/questions/tagged/php), they do not mean the same thing. A [synonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym) is a word or phrase that means exactly or nearly the same as another word or phrase in the same language.